# Make Python 3 wait for keyboard input

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a way to say `Press any key to continue`, and the user can press any key on their keyboard to continue the program. I'm currently using `input("Press Enter to continue")`, but this is not optimal for my project.

How can I make Python wait for **any key** to be pressed?

Comment: what have you tried so far? are you creating some graphical instance? what operating system(s) are you targeting?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6 for Windows 10, and at the moment I'm making a simple menu interface. I'm very new to Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this

> ```
> import msvcrt as msv
> def wait():
>     msv.getch()
> ```